# Proof $\phi(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=\theta$ is not Lipschitz.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Taking $S=\lbrace(x,y)\in\mathbf{R}^2:1<x^2+y^2<9\rbrace\backslash ( [0,\infty)\times\lbrace 0\rbrace),$ and defining $\phi:S\to\mathbf{R}$ as $\phi(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=\theta$ for $1<r<3$ and $0<\theta<2\pi,$ how would I go about showing that $\phi$ is not Lipschitz? I have been given a comment that $\phi$ is a $C^\infty$-function and any partial derivative of $\phi$ will be bounded, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Please can someone explain or suggest a method of attack to this?

I know I must show that there is no $K\in\mathbf{R}$ such that $|\phi(v)-\phi(u)|\leq K\|v-u\|$ for all $v,u\in S,$ but I don't know which theorems are useful here, and the result is not intuitive to me. Even just a name of a theorem to help would be great.

Comment: $\theta=\arctan y/x$.

Comment: Can you expand upon this?

Comment: My previous comment is irrelevant now (see the answer). And the bit "... and any partial derivative of $\phi$ will be bounded..." is false beacause the domain isn't compact.

Comment: I'm not sure if the other answer works, because $1<r,$ so I'm interested in what you had to say.

Comment: use the Mean value theorem in several variables (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_in_several_variables).

Comment: Note: Slicing the annulus by removing the positive $x$-axis is essential here. Otherwise $\theta$ is not a continuous function of $(x,y)$. So concentrate on the vicinity of the positive real axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $u = r(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ and $v = r(\cos\theta',\sin\theta')$ with $\theta' - \theta \equiv \epsilon$. For $\epsilon \ll 1$ we have

$$|u-v| = r(\epsilon + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^3))$$

Now if
$$|\phi(u) - \phi(v)| \leq K|u-v|$$

holds then $K$ must satisfy

$$\frac{1}{r} < K$$

for all $0<r<3$ which is not possible as the left hand side diverges for $r\to 0^+$.

Edit:

If you change it to $1<r<3$ then take, as suggested by Jyrki, $\theta = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $\theta' = 2\pi - \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. This gives $|\theta-\theta'| = 2\pi-\epsilon$ and $|u-v| = r\epsilon + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^3)$ which (for $\epsilon \ll 1$) implies $$\frac{2\pi-\epsilon}{r\epsilon} < K$$

Comment: Thanks, can't upvote because new account, but thank you.

Comment: Actually, just to clarify, $1<r<3,$ not $0<r<3.$ I don't think $r\to 0$ is valid.

Comment: @erst Well your original question had $0<r<3$. But if you want to change the question then this does not work anymore! The idea behind this still stands: look for two points to show that $K$ is not bounded. See Jyrki's comment.